# Выборка случайного идентификатора из таблицы

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть выборка с таблицы :

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM enemy WHERE id = 1")
```

Как сделать, чтоб id выбирался случайным обазом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `enemy` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1';
```

Так-же, из совета [[@chernomyrdin](/users/3261/chernomyrdin)](/users/3261/chernomyrdin), привожу более быструю реализацию:

```
SELECT `enemy`.*
FROM `enemy`, ( SELECT CEIL( RAND() * (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `enemy`) ) AS `id` ) AS `rand`
WHERE `enemy`.`id` >= `rand`.`id`
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: А что в конце значит 1 ?

Comment: 1 - это сколько записей вы хотите выбрать

Comment: Решение простое, но не слишком оптимальное особенно для высокоагруженных проектов.

Подробнее см. http://hudson.su/2010/09/16/mysql-optimizaciya-order-by-rand/